# Upgrade Yii version form 2.0.6 to 2.0.45 error in parameters null

Tags: php, yii2

Actually i begin the upgrade for Yii framework and have the next error:

class_exists(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($class) of type string is deprecated

in C:\wamp\www...\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\src\panels\UserPanel.php

I upgrade the yii version from 2.0.6 to 2.0.45 and the php version from 5.5.12 to 8.1.13

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FBv2.png)

My composer.json:

```js
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-queue": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "yiisoft/yii2-composer": true
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type":"composer",
        "url":"https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's a [known](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/issues/477) [bug](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/issues/465). It looks like Yii2 is not quite compatible with PHP 8.1 yet

Comment: recommend version of php for yii?

Comment: 8.0 is good to go